# How to set screen resolution for ipad 3

Tags: css

Hey All i m bit new to ipad -3 designing. Can any one guide me how to set media queries for ipad-3.thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

The new iPad has the same width and height as the first and second iPad so you just need to apply the same media queries:

```
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  .ipad-portrait { color: red; } /* your css rules for ipad portrait */
}

@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .ipad-landscape { color: blue; } /* your css rules for ipad landscape */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 3/4) {

          // your styles here
     }
```